# How does one unfreeze an NFT to send to other wallets?

Tags: freeze-token-account, freeze

I have 4 NFT editions that are supposedly frozen in my account so they can't be sent. I received this correspondence from the Phantom support but I have no idea where to begin.

Hi there,

It seems that the NFTs you can't send are frozen in your account, this is probably why you can't move them. You can verify this in the solscan link of the NFT transaction, specifically in instruction #2.7 Metaplex Token Metadata: Freeze Delegated Account and #2.8 FreezeAccount

https://solscan.io/tx/ZufzjnLg1dTY3fhaeEynk4XvZDufyWvHrCCEPvQr2H32zphWjK4P8zbL2Dr3k6rTB114JJHWasEthHDrvJpTH75
https://solscan.io/tx/66bXM3eJqiKt26Ps8u35pZJfpnXhEuJbhvbNcntPZNoZrRDf8jXemYJARb8f7gG3Nmdd97JhE76oijJWph8upxu8
https://solscan.io/tx/2Wjv9e4rLMQ4ar7PgqM4D4dJRHiUPXmc9etyPvhMyaC6nUAbpi9RoQGNC8Q2CefycaErZNUe5uEsXPFFnJYyB3ej
https://solscan.io/tx/3YXC9UmU3JG3649BWSB9X7UGpXVGrgMrmjAWhJ64pL82ovPeetiG6kP3nMVrdNNcsazTrHkaFePiyeeeSSVVpuc

I minted NFTs via exchang.art which is an art platform and am attempting to send them to other collectors. Am I supposed to edit the contract? I have no idea how to do so. Sorry for the very noob question. I'm just an artist starting off on Solana and have no prior knowledge to coding.

Comment: Whoever has freeze authority must unfreeze them I think

Answer (score 2):

If the tokens are frozen, someone must unfreeze / thaw them before allowing a transfer.  The freeze authority on one of the token mints (https://solscan.io/token/49sS8JFqjXkZGnW5vKBTWc1E5yYKrPKxVMTfK2i1nW6i) is owned by the Metaplex Metadata Program https://solscan.io/account/8kR7xCKadqSfxGvyZCBuGdL4S9niVAB5a6AGUzEgYDK4, which means that you must go through Metaplex to move these tokens.

I'm not sure what functionality they provide, but I hope that this points you in the right direction!